# How can you stop a long (perhaps an infinite loop) internal emacs command?

Tags: loops, emacs, infinite

Sometimes emacs enter in a loop, and I can't do anything but kill it.

I don't really know the exact key combination that I use to put it in that state.

Something with CTRL and %

Comment: When I kill it, the file I can recover have megabits of %%%% inserted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is Ctrl-g what you are looking for?

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `C-g` (`keyboard-quit`) is what you want. `C-g` is short for `Ctrl-g`. The `keyboard-quit` command tells Emacs to **interrupt** the current command (lisp code) that it is processing.

To get information about this command, enter the following in the minibar:

```
M-x describe-key C-g
```

**-or-**

```
C-h k C-g
```

*(`M-x` is generally mapped to `Alt-x` on Windows.)*

```
C-g runs the command keyboard-quit
   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple'.
(keyboard-quit)

Signal a `quit' condition.
During execution of Lisp code, this character causes a quit directly.
At top-level, as an editor command, this simply beeps.
```